# Angular JWT Token is added to lazyUpdate instead of headers in HttpHeaders

Tags: angular

I have a problem that JWT token is not added to headers only on specific API and I don't know why..
**The content of httpOptions.headers is different in each function as you can see in the screenshots below.**

**My bookmarks service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { UserAuthService } from '../user-auth/user-auth.service'; 
import { Bookmark } from 'src/app/models/api/bookmarks/Bookmark';

let httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }),
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BookmarksService {
  jwtToken: string | null = this.userAuthService.getJwtToken();

  private apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private userAuthService: UserAuthService
  ) {}

  // Get bookmarks
  getBookmarks(): Observable<Bookmark> {
    this.addJwtToHeaders();

    const url: string = `${this.apiUrl}/bookmark/`;
    return this.http.get<Bookmark>(url, httpOptions);
  }

  addToBookmark(id: string): Observable<any> {
    this.addJwtToHeaders();
    console.log(httpOptions.headers);

    const url: string = `${this.apiUrl}/bookmark_add/${id}/`;
    return this.http.post<any>(url, httpOptions);
  }

  addJwtToHeaders(): void {
    const auth = httpOptions.headers.get('Authorization');
    if (!auth) {
      if (!this.jwtToken) return;
      httpOptions.headers = httpOptions.headers.append(
        'Authorization',
        `Token ${this.jwtToken}`
      );
    }
  }
}
```

So the function **getBookmarks()** works, but function **addToBookmark()** doesn't.

**getBookmarks()**
[image]

**addToBookmark()** - error 401 Unauthorized
[image]

**The console log in the addToBookmark() function is:**
[image]

**And the console log in the getBookmarks() function:**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This signature for `http.post()` is different from `http.get()`.

- GET: `get(url, options)`
- POST: `post(url, body, options)`

So in your POST request, you are passing your `options` in the `body` parameter.

You can fix by adding your body data:

```
this.http.post<any>(url, body, httpOptions)
```